# Flash player fall-back controls not working in fullscreen IE

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm using video.js and sequence.js together.

In IE, the flash fallback works and plays the video, but if you enter fullscreen the controls won't work anymore.

This is where I'm having the issue:
http://sandbox.israel-rn.info/axaTRES/modulo9.html

Comment: It doesn't appear that page is using video.js anymore. Does the video.js homepage work for you in IE? What version of IE?

Comment: Yes, sorry.. We switched to Flowplayer instead.